# Prime factors of $\sum_{k=1}^{30}k^{k^k}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, tetration

I checked the prime factors of

$$\sum_{k=1}^{30}k^{k^k}$$

and did not find any upto $10^8$

Are there any useful restrictions to accelerate the search ?

Comment: This is an interesting question on it's own,  but could you tell us how did this come up?

Comment: I just searched the smallest prime factors of z(n) := $\sum_{k=1}^nk^{k^k}$ and the largest one occured for n=9 (it is 205991). And n=30 is the least n, such that z(n) has no small prime factors.

Comment: How are you currently doing this?

Comment: I use the powermod routine to calculate z(n) mod p

Comment: I have several ideas on how to test primes faster(FLT, sieving), but no one on how to dismiss primes without testing them, and I don't want to be redundant. Please show your current method to see if I can do any improvement to it(or if your method is better than the one I have in mind I would like to see it)

Comment: I use trial division because the numbers are too big to be tested for primality. It would be nice to have a method to calculate z(n) mod p faster.

Comment: Are you reducing the red part of $k^{\color{red}{k^k}}$ mod $p-1$?

Comment: Yes, I did that. Without that, the calculation is awfully slow.

Comment: This is only unproblematic for primes greater than n (so that gcd(p,$k^k$)=1 is guaranteed), but for relatively small n, this is no great problem.

Comment: **Please** add all the info and thoughts you have so far so that we can stop guessing about your method, it helps everyone to undeestand and help you better.

Comment: I wrote a small C program using the n_powmod2_preinv function in the Flint Number Theory Library. I used the tricks you already mentioned and checked up to $5\cdot10^{10}$ and didn't find any factors.

Comment: I have already described what I have done.